# Properly formatted caching for .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, gzip, cache-control, mod-expires, mod-headers

I just wish to check If code for .htacess file is good. I wish to implement catching on site, so I found code and edited just time for my needs.

I wish to cache **flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|swf** files for 1 month, **gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css** files for 2 weeks, **xml|txt|htm|html** files for 1 day and not to cache **php|cgi|pl** files.

What I need is this:

1. Is Code ok, or there is maybe some mistake in it?
2. Do I need both mod_headers.c and mod_expires.c in my .htacces file, and can be both, or just one?

This is code for .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A86400        
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A1209600
    ExpiresByType text/css A1209600
    ExpiresByType image/gif A1209600
    ExpiresByType image/png A1209600
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A1209600
    ExpiresByType text/plain A86400
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2592000
    ExpiresByType video/x-flv A2592000
    ExpiresByType application/pdf A2592000
    ExpiresByType text/html A86400
    </IfModule>

<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
## Turn on Expires and set default expires to 1 day
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A86400

## Set up caching on media files for 1 month
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|swf)$">
  ExpiresDefault A2592000
  Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

## Set up caching on images css and js files for 2 weeks
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)$">
  ExpiresDefault A1209600
  Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

## Set up 1 day caching on commonly updated files
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|htm|html)$">
  ExpiresDefault A86400 
  Header append Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

## Force no caching for dynamic files
<FilesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl)$">
  ExpiresDefault A0 
  Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
  Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
</ifmodule>
```

And do I need to put this too

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</ifModule>
FileETag None
```

And also which is better for compression to use:

```
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>
```

or

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Just use the parts of the htaccess from the html5boilerplate: http://html5boilerplate.com/template/htaccess.txt . The website also has some more info on what does what.

Comment: Thank you for your res response.